# How to get length of row from a rowsorted table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowsorter

This is the code I have. It basically sorts the table based on what the user entered. The problem I have is i cannot retrieve the number of rows after the search.  I have tried (rowSorter.getModel().getRowCount()); but it doesnt seem to work.

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter(jTable.getModel());
    jTable.setRowSorter(rowSorter);
    String text = SearchTF.getText();

    if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
        rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
    } else {
        rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
    }
```

Comment: `JTable#getRowCount`? - Don't use the model, the model is unaffected by a sorter/filter, the view is what's updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TableRowSorter` will not affect the model, it generates a "proxy" of the model which the table can use to display the results.

Instead, ask the `JTable` for the row count - See [`JTable#getRowCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getRowCount--)